# Python returns TypeError: slice indices must be integers or None or have an __index__ method when searching for a key from a dictionary in a string

Tags: python, dictionary, xlrd

I have this code that imports strings from an Excel file. After importing every cell of that file, the data is stored into a 2d array named `data[col][row]`
I have to define a dictionary that contains keys that can be found in the cells.
One cell can contain multiple keys inside, and the code has to recognize all of them.

```
import xlrd
book = xlrd.open_workbook("c:/Users/uids3896/desktop/VWexport.xlsx")
print ("The number of worksheets is", book.nsheets)
print ("Worksheet name(s):", book.sheet_names())
sh = book.sheet_by_index(0)
print (sh.name, sh.nrows, sh.ncols)
print ("Cell D30 is", sh.cell_value(rowx=29, colx=3))
data = [[sh.cell_value(r, c) for c in range(sh.ncols)] for r in range(sh.nrows)]

def issa(s):
    try:
        float(s)
        return True
    except ValueError:
        return False

dict={ 'ID' : 'this would be the return for ID '}
dict['1. Press  BT1 button for T= T_SHORT'] =  'this would be the return for BT1SHORTPRESS'
for col in range (sh.ncols):
    for row in range(sh.nrows):
        for key in dict.keys():
            a=data[col][row]
            s=issa(data[col][row])
            if s:
                c=1
            else:
                if a.find(a, key):
                    print (key)
```

But when I run the code it gives me:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\uids3896\Desktop\New Text Document.py", line 34, in <module>
if a.find(a, key):
TypeError: slice indices must be integers or None or have an __index__ method
```

How to properly search if a string contains a key, and not only one, how to check for all of them, and concatenate the coresponding string from the dictionary in the order they occur in the string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"How to properly search if a key contains a key?"

If by that you mean "How to check if a dictionary key is present in a string:

```
for key in dict.keys():
... 
    if key in string: <do stuff>
```

That's because both your keys are strings.

If you want to check that any element of the dictionary's keys is present in the string:

```
if any(x in str(a) for x in list(dict.keys())):
```

Example

```
test_string = 'This is a test string 1. Press  BT1 button for T= T_SHORT testeteditesttest ID blablah'
dict={ 'ID' : 'this would be the return for ID '}
dict['1. Press  BT1 button for T= T_SHORT'] =  'this would be the return for BT1SHORTPRESS'
any(x in test_string for x in list(dict.keys()))
```

After going over the q&a below, here's how I would do it:

```
for col in range (sh.ncols):
    for row in range(sh.nrows):
        # Moved reading the value fron col/row out of the for because it made no sense to read it for every key in the dict
        a=data[col][row]
        for key in dict.keys():
            s=issa(data[col][row])
            if s:
                c=1
            else:
                 if key in a:
                    a = a.replace(key, dict[key])
        data[col][row] = a
        <save and close the excel or do other things to it>
```

Comment: yes, that was what i meant, i edited now. 
This is an example of a cell:
"
1. Send valid LF Go with TRUNK Telegram 

2. Verify the start time for battery measurement

3. Save the oscilloscope diagrams and put them as remarks in TestRaport

4. Repeat steps 1 and 2 for Keyminder with Trunk Telegram

5. Repeat steps 1 and 2 for Easy Close Telegram
"
Some keywords are in the dictionary and have a corresponding "translation", I need to export for each cell, the coresponding "translations" for the substrings that are keys in the dictionary and ignore the rest.

Comment: So if I understand correctly your dictionary keys are substrings in your parsed string and you want to apply a transformation to that string so that you will replace your keys with their dictionary values in your resulting string. Say your string is '1 2 3 4 blabla 5 6 ' and your dictionary is {'bla': 'notBla'} the result of the transformation, as I understand it, should be the string '1 2 3 4 notBla 5 6'. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes that is absolutelly corect!

Comment: I'll try to modify your implementation and edit the answer. Please test it and update.

Comment: Yes, Thank You very much. It does replace the key if is contained, but Only the first one. If in a string are 2 keys, only the first one is proccessed, but i guess i cand fix that with a loop

Comment: It should replace every key it finds in a (which is the string you read from the cell) with it's translation value. If you only get one value replaced then something is not right. I tested it with the following code and for me it works: `>>> dict = {'1': 'cici', '2': 'dada'}
>>> test_string = '1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4'
>>> for key in dict.keys():
...     if key in test_string:
...             test_string = test_string.replace(key, dict[key])
...
>>> test_string
'cici dada 3 4 cici dada 3 4 cici dada 3 4'`